# how to generate scaladoc on files recursively for files in sub-directories

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I am using {scaladoc} to generate documentation for my scala files, is there away to generate from files in subdirectories ?

Comment: Is using sbt an option? `sbt doc` will run scala-doc for all your sources together

Comment: Is it possible without sbt? Pure scaladoc?